# How to deep fetch In Strapi cms compnents?

Tags: node.js, database, content-management-system, strapi, bookshelf.js

I have the following user API from Strapi cms to which I want to deep fetch address component(repeatable component).

[image]

So, what I want to fetch is the user whose address is `63 Southlands Road`... I tried so many ways:

- tried the Strapi built-in query

> `http://localhost:1337/users?address.info=63%20Southlands%20Road`

- tried the custom query:

  ```
   const result = await strapi
     .query("user")
     .model.query((qb) => {
       qb.where("address.info", "63 Southlands Road");
     })
     .fetch();
  ```

All these above messages didn't work out and I run out of options. Is this possible in Strapi... if not I am trying to switch to node server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Strapi` there's no way of querying the models based on the nested component data directly. But you can use a raw query instead to query the component data and get the desired result. The table names are based on the model name in context, as `Strapi` follows this particular naming convention and automatically creates the tables when you create the `content-types` in admin.

###### Naming convention followed by `Strapi`

If you create a model called `user` and create two components in it for example, `address` and `location` then `Strapi` will create 4 tables as follows:

1. users - This is the table that actually stores the model data
2. users_components - This table stores a mapping of all the components that the user model has for each record
3. components_users_address - This table will store the data about all the `address` components linked to the `user` model
4. components_users_location - The table will store the data about all the `location` components linked to the `user` model

You can cross check the table names by opening up your project database via `pg-admin` or `php-myadmin`.

###### Solution

```js
let result = await strapi.connections.default.raw(
"SELECT u.*
 FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN users_components uc
 ON (uc.user_id = u.id AND uc.component_type='components_users_address' AND uc.field='address')
 LEFT JOIN components_users_address cua ON (cua.id = uc.component_id)
 WHERE AND cua.ifno LIKE '63 Southlands Road'");
console.log(result);
```

**P.S: I've only tried this in `MySQL` and `PostGreSQL`**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but my user is a model, not a component... only the address is a component. I don't have  users_components in my pg-admin? where is `users_components` is came from ?

Comment: Yes, this is the naming convention followed by `Strapi` while generating the tables in the background while you create the `content-types` in the admin. So if your model is `users`, and you have a components in that model, then it will create tables as 1. `users`: Model  2. users_components: this will basically store a mapping of all the components that the user model has for each entry 3.components_users_address: this is the actual component table and will store the address data. if you created one more component called location, then there will be a table called `components_users_location`

Comment: @MaiRich I've updated my answer to explain this better.

Comment: Merci brother, this is working just fine.

Comment: Happy to hear that.. Chao!